# Node js cors proxy results in forbidden

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to communicate with an api with react. I was getting a cors error so i created a proxy api. I'm still getting a 403 error but this time it's different. I get a captcha error. I get data when i open the url in browser and also when i make a request in postman, but not through node js

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const url = `URL_TO_EXTERNAL_API`;
  axios.get(url)
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
  .then(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`http://localhost:${port}`));
```

[here's a portion of the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKA2m.png)

Here's the react request ->

```js
fetch(local, { 
  method: 'get', 
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}).then(response => {
  return response.json();;
}).then(data => {
  this.setState({ announcements: data })
});
```

where local is `"http://localhost:8000?params..."`

Do you know why the current solution is not working ?

Comment: I've tried to be more explicit, both by creating heaeders like so:  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type') and also by putting more info into the cors definition in app.use(cors({...})). neither seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The website or service behind `URL_TO_EXTERNAL_API` has some kind of captcha check to make sure that only humans can view the website. So basically you can't proxy that service, unless your proxy can bypass the captcha check.